# Macbook air A 1466 no power on

Tags: javascript

I have Macbook air A1466 no power on, if I unplug the touchpad cable, plug power in it boot up as it used to,but plug it back, plug power in it has no response at all, I wonder if I replace the touchpad, shoud it fix the problem!?

Comment: 1. This is at all related to JavaScript 2. This is not related to programming.

Comment: @VLAZ - While this question has nothing to do with Javascript it certainly cannot be answered by this community.  *There is no information of any substance that even hints at the reason the author's Macbook will not turn on.*  The author has a hardware problem, and based on the description of the problem, needs it to take it to somebody with the skills to replace the relevant ICs.

Comment: " I wonder if I replace the touchpad, should it fix the problem!?" Only way to find out is to try that.

Comment: @HungVan , would you please edit your question to remove the javascript tag?  Then edit the text so that there is more info about why the power doesn't come on.  Generally, MacBooks are not designed to be opened and user-serviced.